# What should I do if I am unsure if a post is spam or just poorly written?

Tags: discussion, spam

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518522/small-jquery-prevents-other-pages-from-working) in my feed that asks to follow a link to look at a site that the poster claims to be "having issues" with.  At the very end of the post he signs off with another link to his home page (a different URL completely).

I was going to flag it as spam, or at the very least a poor question but I just wanted to get a sanity check.  Is it spam, or just a badly written question?  I'm beginning to think the latter rather than the former.

There is no supplied code in the question and it's getting downvoted quite a bit, so I suspect it may be closed anyway, but I would like someone with more experience to give their opinion.

Since the question has been subsequently closed, I suppose I should modify my question slightly to a more generic one and ask, "If you see a post like this where you're unsure under which category it falls, should you simply flag it as off topic?"

Comment: Since the first link goes to something that's quite offensive, I would 100% call it spam!

Comment: Besides an unfortunate name, how is it offensive?  It appears to be a script by Mig Reyes to deal with excessive resizing.  (GitHub: http://github.com/migreyes/jquery.wanker)

Comment: Needless to say I didn't click the links, but I saw the URL :O  It's been subsequently closed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing at that URL except the empty shell of a future website, so I don't see how it could be spam.

Comment: I didn't click on the link (at work) as I wasn't sure if it was NSFW, but the URL gave me pause, and with the signature all I saw was a post with two remote links and no code.  In future I'll just flag them as Alexei's answer suggests.

Comment: He suggested a moderator flag?  I don't see anything there that is actionable.

Comment: I would flag as off topic or too broad.  It's certainly not answerable in its current format.

Comment: Oh.  You don't have close privileges.

Comment: No, just a mere low rep user trying to do her civic duty :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of that post (including signature at the end with whatever link is there) should be removed as "thank you", "new here", "help me" notes and signature.

After initial edit (real or imaginary) there is a sentence that says there is a problem, and some link to external script (that is not by itself a problem).

So:

- first link - unrelated, unlikely to be classified as spam (I'd be very surprised if author of any plugin to jQuery will spam own plugin with question of such questionable quality)
- second link (signature) - should be edited out as signature, so unless there are other indications of spam by the user it does not call for spam flag.
- this post clearly falls under "Close-> Questions seeking debugging help..." reason since it is about code problem without any traces of code.

As Robert Harvey pointed out if post is unlikely to be useful there is no need to actually perform edit - just ignore parts that shouldn't be there when voting.

Comment: The edit is a waste of time.  The post is six downvotes deep, and your edit isn't going to salvage it (get it reopened).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I know - that why I've said "or imaginary" - I'm not saying that one need to go and actually edit post unless there is a chance to recover it (maybe need to clarify)... I've edited post itself as I hope OP would be able to improve future posts - no expectation of recovering that one.