# What should one do with a question where the questioner seems unable to understand compile error messages?

Tags: discussion, support

A question I saw today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214080/invalid-use-of-void-expression-whats-wrong-with-this-code-pointers-to-functi

I find it hard to see that this is a useful question. The compiler message (unlike some I have seen) is clear and to the point. But it's not the first case I've seen where the compiler message included in the question tells you what the problem is.

So what is the recommended response to this? To mark as off-topic as a typo error (which seems a popular option), to mark as off-topic (custom reason - compiler says exactly what the problem is), to ignore the question, to downvote it - or something else?

Comment: I can't imagine in the case of compiler errors this is the first post. Looking for a duplicate achieves two goals: The OP gets help, The question gets closed. I'm not enough into C to select a good fit [but this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+too+few+arguments+to+function+) renders 256 hits...

Comment: @rene That means the asker is not only too lazy to read the compiler error, s/he is too lazy to do a search for that error. Do we really want to be encouraging such vampires?

Comment: @IanKemp hmm, maybe not but having enough sign-post duplicates might increase the chance google produces something useful if the next visitors starts their search there. I agree on the lack of research so appropriate voting is warranted.

Comment: @rene In this particular case, I would hope that 256 duplicates is more than enough...

Comment: I don't know in how many ways those C-compilers generate errors ... My first response to seeing 256 hits was *this can't be a coincidence*

Comment: I'm sure it's not coincidental that people don't bother to read what the compiler says. But those 256 matches are for a lot more than one function so the OP (if they bother checking) likely think 'this is a different problem because that's not my function they're having a problem with'

Comment: And it's not just C(++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215515/use-character-like-%C3%AB-and-%C3%A7-in-python-file - not sure if that makes me happy or sad

Comment: If you think that's bad, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195202/threads-and-parameter-name-omitted-funtion

Comment: I guess it would depend on what we consider assumed knowledge for a programmer participating on this site. Should we assume they know what an "argument" is, in the programming sense of the word? There are highly upvoted questions on SO asking exactly what an argument is! e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176310/difference-between-parameter-and-argument) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252812/what-is-an-argument)

Comment: @TomTanner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215515/use-character-like-%C3%AB-and-%C3%A7-in-python-file actually looks reasonable at a glance - the part of the error message that they've quoted *doesn't* tell you what you need to do to be able to include non-ASCII characters in the file. What will be non-obvious to non-Python folks though is that that's merely because he left out the part of the error message that does!

Comment: The question in question is deleted BTW.

Comment: We are all accustomed to ignoring error message text.  This is because we all write bad error messages and bad error handling, then we get used to messages being meaningless, as if the software is just grunting to indicate a problem, and the cause is always hidden and needs to be puzzled through.  When was the last time you wrote error handling with an IF statement in it, distinguishing between different causes?   versus just grunting.

Comment: Its that time of the year, 1st Year CS students given their first programming homework.

Comment: @OsamaBinLogin about a month ago actually

Comment: The questioner probably knows less than you (quite possibly a lot less). In fact he/she might be at the same learning stage that you were several years ago. Always bear that in mind before venting frustration at the idiots you are surrounded with. :-). The comments referring to idiotic error messages 9which abound) are also a mitigating factor.

Comment: The questioner probably knows less than you (quite possibly a lot less). In fact he/she might be at the same learning stage that you were several years ago. Always bear that in mind before venting frustration at the idiots you are surrounded with. :-). The comments referring to idiotic error messages (which abound) are also a mitigating factor.I had one recently (from a Microsfot product, would you believe) that said "The following error occured: there were one or more errors".  Hmmm.. I don't understand what it is telling me.

Comment: Why would you even care if you see such questions? Ignore it. There are lots of ppl, who might point dumbass into correct line into stack trace

Comment: @NeilHaughton I was excluding incomprehensible messages. The (closed) question the compiler rror was pretty much telling thm exactly what the problem was. If it had been one of the 40 line template error messages that seem popular with our current compiler, I'd have given them plenty of leeway. Even my first foray into computing I did make some effort to understand what the compiler was saying (especially as there was no SO at the time)

Comment: If only we had the "RTFM" close reason...

Comment: Whenever my code switches from GCC to visual studio, the errors throw me for a while.  Sometimes the compiler is thrown by an earlier statement,  so the error is misleading.  Mark duplicates but do let new to coding people benefit from our experience

Comment: @TomTanner The point being made to you is even though *you* find a message trivial to comprehend that does not mean it is so for all people. A good chunk of people reading this question and not bothering to comment are probably in awe of its trivial meaningless and ultimately destructive nature. Its a humble brag at best.

Comment: Yes, let’s weed out questions that are pure laziness — but also exercise caution when judging questions as such. I work with students a lot, and am constantly reminded of how many “obvious” things are in fact not obvious at all. Keep in mind that a question’s author might be a bare beginner or a non-native speaker struggling with terminology, and be patient. If a question seems obvious but is clearly and carefully stated, go ahead and give the obvious answer simply stated, without great effort but without condescension either. That’s good teaching, and good community-building.

Comment: @JohnNicholas Asking what I should do is destructive?

Comment: @TomTanner Suggesting some action is needed simply because someones level of comprehension is lower than yours. It's not you its an attitude that permeates this site now. It's like a kind of well meaning righteousness that is simply a way of joining the club. Just look at the most upvoted answer to see my point. The simplest instruction is incomprehensible if you look at it wrong.

Answer (score 26):

My vote, if I had one to spend would be for this off-topic close reason:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Particularly the part about being unlikely to help future readers, and that the issue could have been identified by closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem.

In the future, as was suggested to me by [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306420/is-this-spam-or-is-it-acceptable#comment249194_306421), you can always ask for advice at the [SO Close Vote Reviewers (SOCVR) chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: if they didn't read the error, good bet they don't read the close reason either

Comment: @charlietfl: or the answers they will get... so might as well close it!

Comment: @charlietfl They most certainly read the error as they were very careful to provide exactly the code relevant to the error and no more/less than that.

Answer (score 14):

I think the close reason isn't applicable here.  This is a case of someone who doesn't understand some fundamental concepts of the language, and these error messages will certainly be encountered by others who begin to wet their feet in function pointers and do not yet have a solid understanding of function pointers and function signatures.

1) It wasn't a typographical error.  It's not as if he accidentally fat-fingered the series of keys consisting of "sort_ins(v,n)".  It wasn't a typo.  He clearly intended to type exactly this.  The error was not the result of a typo, it was the result of a lack of understanding of function signatures.

2) "a problem that can no longer be reproduce" is also completely wrong.  I can certainly reproduce this problem.  This close reason is intended for problems where no one can reproduce the problem, and the asker is unable to provide enough details to clarify the scenario in which the problem occurs.  You can easily reproduce this error with code given.  In fact, he did a pretty good job of providing just enough code to identify the problem.  How rare is that?  We usually either get pages of irrelevant code, or we get too little code where the error is not related to any of the code shown.  He actually took the time to at least inspect the error and provide the code surrounding the context of the error, as well as provide declarations of the functions being passed as arguments.

3) A novice programmer will not immediately understand that "void expression" translates to "a function(or other expression) that returns void" and "invalid use of" is too vague to indicate to them that the function signature does not match the expected signature.

If there was a close reason that was appropriate, it would be the deprecated close reason of "too localized".  However, even then I think there is an answer that would have been enlightening to a larger group of novice developers who encounter this error.  **I think anyone venturing into function pointers for the first time is likely to stumble on these things until the understand the concepts of function signatures.**  I would have tried to bridge the gap in understanding between the error message, and get them to pay attention to function signatures:

> The first parameter to the `test1` function expects this signature:
>
> `int (*order) ( int[] , int )`
>
> ...however `sort_ins` has a signature with a different return type of
>   `void` instead of `int`:
>
> `void (* )(int v[],int n)`
>
> See the difference between these two?  These are called function signatures, and they must match.
>    That is the source of the first
>   "invalid use of void expression" because you are passing a function
>   that returns void(a void expression) when it expects an int return
>   instead of void.
>
> You have exactly the same problem with inicializacion, as it returns
>   void as well.
>
> After fixing those two errors, it'll probably be more obvious that the
>   "too few arguments to function ‘test1’" error is because you've only
>   passed two arguments to test1 instead of four, missing the last `,int v[],int n)`.

This is really a case of people not remembering what it was like when you first started programming and have all these non-descript errors flying at you.

If he doesn't take the time to try and make the connection after such an answer, then he needs to step back and re-familiarize with the fundamentals.  I think it's reasonable to make an attempt to fill the gap between the vague(relative to a novice) error and link that to the concepts of function signatures.

It's also a case of really stretching the meaning of a close category as per my points #1 and #2, just to serve a desire to close a question that rubs you the wrong way.  I know I'm gonna get a flood of downvotes, but you can't deny that it wasn't a typo and it is certainly reproducible.

Comment: I agree. I too have to remind myself how it was when I was learning some aspect of programming and how sometimes when I asked (seemingly) stupid questions didn't always mean *I* was stupid... sometimes I was... just not *all* the time lol.